# Express Static files not working on Catch-all address

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a 404 page on my website, but on a nested page (for example test1/test2) static files aren‘t working.

Below is an example for a page with only one part. The css file works normal.

```
app.get("/:part1", (req, res) => {
  res.render("404")
});
```

If I go to *domain*/test i will get a page with the static style.css:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrmLf.jpg

Below is an example for a page two parts. The css file doesn‘t load.

```
app.get("/:part1/:part2", (req, res) => {
  res.render("404")
});
```

Now if I go to *domain*/test1/test2 I will still get the message, but not the css:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/70SHn.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. In the html file I needed to change:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

to:

```
<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the express.static method for static files :

```
const path = require('path')
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```